# Search value in same array and replace it

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [parent] => #
            [text] => Shb2-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [parent] => 16
            [text] => Shb2-3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [parent] => 17
            [text] => Shb2-4
        )

)
```

I would like to search if [parent] value exist in the same array as [id]

If it do not exist exists, then the [parent] value will be replaced to 0.

**Example:**

check if the value 16 exists in the whole array as [id] (in my example available [id] are 15, 17 and 18).

if it do not exist, 16 will be replaced by 0.
Then check for the next array key, and so until I get un output with final replaced values.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: array_search and custom function. Couldn't make a check for [key][parent] and [all-other-keys][id]

Comment: `array_search` won't work for multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to change `parent` to zero if it is not equal to any `id`, then I think this simple code will do it:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    // Search if 'id' exists in the array
    $a_key = array_search($val['parent'], array_column($array, 'id'));
    // Check if 'id' is in the array, if not then replace 'parent' with 0
    if ($a_key == false) $array[$key]['parent'] = '0';
}
```

Comment: I do not want it to check only for the last [id] but for all the [id] that exists in the array :)

Comment: @Cartha oh sorry, I edited the code, check if that's what you asked for

Comment: Oh great. It works for me. I just changed this: ($a_key === false). Thanks a lot @Sayed Mujtaba